# Editing .git/config file filled with special characters

Tags: git, macos, encoding, git-submodules

I'm working with submodules in a repository and it's created a number of strange issues that I've never dealt with while working with git before.

When attempting to add a submodule to a directory (that has existed in that directory in the past), I'm getting an `A git directory for 'auth' is found locally with remote(s):` error.

I have already

1. Removed the submodule details from my `.gitmodules` file
2. Removed the submodule from `.git/modules`
3. Done a `git rm` and `git rm --cached` and a standard `rm -rf` to that directory. (to which all fail, because that folder does not exist in git or on my file structure).

After some research, I was pointed in the direction of editing my `.git/config` file and removing the submodule from there. I open the file and alas, it most definitely is being mentioned in there... however, everyone online just nonchalantly says "Edit your `.git/config` file", but mine is riddled with special characters (I'm opening it in UTF-8) and I can't seem to find anything online about "local git repo .git config file being filled with special characters".

Here is an example of the `.git/config` file:

```
�?�ΧeXbB:
```

The even more odd part is that all of the paths are perfectly legible, it just seems like all meta values are not.

For example

```
�auth/src
```

Comment: are you using Windows?

Comment: @ti7 Using Mac, latest OS with ZSH

Comment: That's quite curious, since most mac tools use UTF-8 by default and Git's own setting encode to the ASCII subset of UTF-8 and therefore Don't Do That. I did see something recently about the new M1 macs having some broken tools in the distributions (in particular perl5 would core dump on loading git-add--interactive).

Comment: @torek I ended up deleting and re-cloning the repo, the config file looks fine now. Super strange.